# How to install orchard in python windows 64 bit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created an App using Python windows 64 bit. Now I want to import orchard. When I installed orchard it showed the following error. please anybody help me.

```
>>> import  orchard
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import  orchard
ImportError: No module named 'orchard
```

'

Comment: thank u sam for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install module `orchard`.
You may use the following command to install it.

```
pip install orchard
```

Make sure that pip is installed in your system.

Refer [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/orchard/1.0.4) for additional help